# Creating Custom Complex Units with astropy.units and Custom Conversions

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am working with astronomical data and need to work with custom units, specifically in Mega Jansky per steradian. I would like to create these custom units using the astropy.units library and also implement a custom conversion function similar to the one provided by astropy .to() that takes my pixel size as a parameter in order to convert into Jy/pixel

I implemented a custom conversion function using the following code: (see example).
While this solution works, I find it somewhat inelegant. Is there a more sophisticated or built-in approach in astropy.units to handle such conversions while taking into account pixel size in arcseconds?

Is it possible to define custom units like Mega Jansky per steradian using astropy.units? If so, could you provide an example of how to define and use them in calculations?

For clarity: I am interested in implementing this custom unit and its conversion parameters because I am working on a pipeline, and being able to define the unit of measurement (which is not always the same) at the beginning would save me a lot of headache.

```
from astropy import units as u


class CustomUnitConverter:
    def __init__(self, value, unit):
        self.value = value
        self.unit = unit

    def to(self, target_unit, pixel_size):
        if self.unit == u.MJy / u.steradian and target_unit == u.Jy / u.pixel:
            sr_to_arcsec = 4.25e10  # conversion factor
            conversion_factor = 1e6 / sr_to_arcsec * (pixel_size**2)
            converted_value = self.value * conversion_factor
            return CustomUnitConverter(converted_value, target_unit)
        
        raise u.UnitConversionError(f"Cannot convert {self.unit} to {target_unit}")

# Example
mjy_per_sr = CustomUnitConverter(10.0, u.MJy / u.steradian)
pixel_size_arcsec = 0.25  # dimesion of px in arcsec
jy_per_pixel = mjy_per_sr.to(u.Jy / u.pixel, pixel_size_arcsec)

print(jy_per_pixel.value)
print(jy_per_pixel.unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/equivalencies.html#writing-new-equivalencies, e.g.:

```py
from astropy import units as u
pixel_scale = 0.1*u.arcsec
equiv = [(u.MJy/u.sr, u.MJy/u.pixel,
          lambda x: (pixel_scale**2).to(u.sr).value * x,
          lambda x: 1/(pixel_scale**2).to(u.sr).value)]
x = 5*u.MJy/u.sr
x.to(u.Jy/u.pixel, equiv)
```

That covers the unit conversion.  If you want a custom unit, you just need to compose them, e.g.:

```py
MJySr = u.MJy/u.sr
JyPx = u.Jy/u.pixel
```